# gdb get current value of variable by it name and change it

Tags: c++, gdb

I have global variable eg `int NUM = 4;`. When I attached to the working application with gdb -  its hang. Now, I want to get value of `NUM` and change it. How to do this?

Maybe, possible examples for other data type like `char[]` and `std::string` ?

thanks

Comment: Can you honestly not work out how to change an array element from the answer below?

Comment: -1 because I googled your question verbatim and found the answer in the first link.

Comment: Come one, guys. Be kinder. We were all beginners once. Sure, folks can "google" for an answer, but not everyone has google-fu, Google might not show everyone the same result, etc. SO is supposed to be a repository of QA, no matter how questions were phrased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gdb you should use

```
    print INT
```

to show the value of INT and

```
    set variable INT = value
```

to set INT equal to value.
In an array use

```
    set variable array_variable[element_index] = value
```

to set the element at index `element_index` in the array `array_variable` to value.